# about synchronous access on a static variable

Tags: c++

I've a doubt about the access on a static variable.
I'm using a simulator that launch every second an application that have to download a file. In  the application's class, I increment a counter declared in another class (you can see below) when the download is finished.
I can see where I run my simulation that if want to obtain the counter value from the main, this value is always a different value (generally very small comparison of the reality value that I expect). So I thought is a problem of synchronization of the different applications that can modify this variable. What do you think?

This is the class where I've declared the counter:

```
//infonet.cc
#include "infonet.h"

namespace ns3 {

uint32_t infonet::totalDownloaded = 0;

void infonet::incrementTotalDownloaded()
{
    totalDownloaded++;
}
```

and in infonet.h I only have as public

```
static uint32_t totalDownloaded; 
static void incrementTotalDownloaded();
infonet();
virtual ~infonet();
```

In the application's class I increment the counter when the application stop (the application stop only if it has finished to download)

```
void
MyClass::StopApplication () 
{
   ....
  infonet::incrementTotalDownloaded();
   ...      
}
```

and in main.cc I have several applications installed, and at the end of simulation I want to obtain the value in this way:

```
uint32_t val = infonet::totalDownloaded;
```

Comment: This is indeed a recipe for a disaster: use one of the atomic integral types available in C++11: ++ on uint21_t is not thread safe.

Comment: Should you be declaring the variable as `static` in the header?

Comment: What is there to say but infrequent, concurrent non-atomic increments are almost safe, but not quite. An increment takes around 3 cycles, so if this happens at a random time _once per second_ on a 3 GHz CPU, there is a 1:1000,000,000 chance that the increment will go wrong. Since you are saying that you regularly see small differences, I assume that you really have much higher concurrency, though. Either way, it doesn't change a thing, for correctness you need to use atomic increments or a lock.

Comment: Thank you all, I'll be to use atomic types!